# how to find the sum of a list with numbers less than 0

Tags: arraylist, average

busa = [0,0,0,2,2,4,0,3,4,-2,-5,0,0,3,4,-1,8,1,1,-2]

I would like it so if i change the numbers in busa it would still be able to calculate the average of the numbers bellow 0

Comment: Be more specific. What language, platform, etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.